# How to replace the n th occurance of a character in a String ?

Tags: java, regex

I need to replace all commas after the 5th one. So if a String contains 10 commans, I want to leave only the first 5, and remove all subsequent commas.

How can I do this ?

```
String sentence = "Test,test,test,test,test,test,test,test"; 
String newSentence = sentence.replaceAll(",[6]","");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just capture all the characters from the start upto the 5th comma and match all the remaining commas using the alternation operator `|`. So `,` after `|` should match all the remaining commas. By replacing all the matched chars with `$1` will give you the desired output.

```
sentence.replaceAll("^((?:[^,]*,){5})|,", "$1");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uD2iX4/1)

Comment: This works, but regexes are really not the tool for the job here.  They're slow, ugly code that typically only the original author understands, and it's really easy to get them slightly wrong.

Comment: works as a charm ! have no idea why and how but it gets the job done thanks

Comment: Because there are rare circumstances when it's necessary and because of the complexity of what you're trying to do you're not gonna take much of a performance hit.  This isn't one of those cases.  Justin Jones has the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

In case you were wondering how to solve this problem without using regular expressions... There are libraries that could make your life easier but here is the first thought that came to mind.

```
public String replaceSpecificCharAfter( String input, char find, int deleteAfter){

    char[] inputArray = input.toCharArray();
    String output = ""; 
    int count = 0;

    for(int i=0; i <inputArray.length; i++){
        char letter = inputArray[i];
        if(letter == find){
            count++;
            if (count <= deleteAfter){
                 output += letter;
            }
         }
         else{
             output += letter;
         }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Then you would invoke the function like so:

```
String sentence = "Test,test,test,test,test,test,test,test"; 
String newSentence = replaceSpecificCharAfter(sentence, ',', 6);
```